# How to restrict function invocation to a particular thread/executor

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin

I'm currently designing database for a mobile application. Recently I found very useful function to access database in background:

```
private val IO_EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

fun ioThread(f : () -> Unit) {
    IO_EXECUTOR.execute(f)
}
```

Besides that I figured out that don't need synchronization code as the database will be accessed only in one thread (i.e the thread used by `SingleThreadExecutor`).

The only issue is that the following methods have to be restricted to be invoked only through `ioThread` function (or using `IO_EXECUTOR`).

```
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {
        fun init(context: Context) { ... }
        fun getInstance() { ... }
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve this in `Kotlin`/`Java`?

---

**UPDATE:** for now I have this implementation but think there should be better ones

```
// App.kt file
private val IO_EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
private var IO_THREAD_ID: Long = -1L

private fun getIOThreadId(): Long {
    if (IO_THREAD_ID == -1L)
        IO_THREAD_ID = IO_EXECUTOR.submit(Callable<Long> { Thread.currentThread().id }).get()

    return IO_THREAD_ID
}

fun notInIOThread() = Thread.currentThread().id != getIOThreadId()

fun ioThread(f : () -> Unit) {
    IO_EXECUTOR.execute(f)
}
```

and then use `notInIOThread()` in `init()` and `getInstance()` functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need to make sure that the code is running on the correct thread, you could make use of a custom thread and then checking `Thread.currentThread()` for the interface.

```
private interface MarkedIOThread // Marker interface

private val IO_EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor { r -> 
    return object : Thread(r), MarkedIOThread 
}

fun notInIOThread(): Boolean = Thread.currentThread() !is MarkedIOThread
```

Comment: yeah absolutely as I want to get rid of syncronization code

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use android annotations`s Worker Thread annotation.

When you annotate a method or class with @WorkerThread, android will give you lint errors if you call it from the UI thread.

You can read more about the @WorkerThread here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/WorkerThread

And more about android annotations here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations

I would suggest that you should check room library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

It is very powerful, if you don't have any specific reason to create a database library, room is your best bet.

Comment: I need more restrictive mechanism. i.e. not for all background processes but for particular ones

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the functions to be called only inside `ioThread` code block, otherwise there'd be a type error. First make them member functions of a class with user-code-inaccessible constructor so others cannot call it directly:

```
class MyDslClass internal constructor() {
    fun init(context: Context) { ... }
    fun getInstance() { ... }
}
```

And `ioThread` should be:

```
fun ioThread(f : MyDslClass.() -> Unit) {
    val dsl = MyDslClass()
    IO_EXECUTOR.execute { dsl.f() }
}
```

Then you can restrict calls to those functions only inside `ioThread` block.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    ioThread {
        getInstance() // Ok
    }
    // cannot call `getInstance` since I cannot construct a `MyDslClass`
}
```

Comment: how, for instance, I can use `ioThread` function in other places to update the database?

Comment: I don't know why you're asking this, you can call `ioThread` everywhere. My answer just restricted the call to `getInstance` and `init`.

Comment: Very interesting approach. I didn't fully understand how functional types with receiver works, but seems it not restrict invocation of `getInstance` if it wrapped in another method, for instance, let's say named `updateMessages`.

Comment: @Maxim Yes but you cannot construct a `MyDslClass` outside of your library code, which means the only one who can get rid of the restriction is you.